# I am not able to log in into the app using Gatling

Tags: scala, api, gatling

I am new to Gatling facing some trouble while log in into the application.

1. There is an API which provides a random no and public key, I have to save these values so that I can parse them to next step.
2. Next step is a post request for entering User-id and password, password gets encrypted.
3. Also I have to save XSRF token from the cookie to maintain the session.
4. Then there is O.T.P authentication which I have to fetch from Rest API.

how do i need to perform all the above in sequence

Comment: You need to save those responses one by one and use it for other requests. First of all open developer tools and navigate to Login page > Login with credentials and check response then write code for the same.

Comment: Hi Peter can you help me with the code for the same. I am not able to achieve the same

Comment: object Actions {
  // fetch public key and Random number and store them back in session
  def retrieveAuthData(session: Session, datakey: String): AuthData = {
    val t: String = session.get(datakey).as[String];
    // retrieve parameters from json
    val publicKey: String = a("PublicKey").asInstanceOf[String];
    val random: String = a("Random").asInstanceOf[String];
    val ds3: Boolean = a("DS3").asInstanceOf[Boolean];
    val twoFA: Boolean = a("TwoFa").asInstanceOf[Boolean];
    return new AuthData(publicKey, random, ds3, twoFA);
  }
}

This if to fetch the response

Comment: @peter can you please help me with this

Answer (score 0):

```
object Actions { 

def retrieveAuthData(session: Session, datakey: String): AuthData = {

// get response as a string
val t: String = session.get(datakey).as[String];
// retrieve parameters from json
val publicKey: String = a("PublicKey").asInstanceOf[String];
val random: String = a("Random").asInstanceOf[String];
val ds3: Boolean = a("DS3").asInstanceOf[Boolean];
val twoFA: Boolean = a("TwoFa").asInstanceOf[Boolean];

return new AuthData(publicKey, random, ds3, twoFA);
 }
}
```